# Aggregating results in Pandas after using mpi4py

Tags: python, pandas, mpi, mpi4py

At last, here is my first question on StackOF:

As a project for uni, I am trying to write a code for KMeans from scratch and then run different repeats with random starting centers in parallel using mpi4py.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[3]:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from mpi4py import MPI
# import statistics as stat

comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
print('no of processors is', size)
print('this is the process #', rank)
df = pd.read_csv('data.dat',
                   sep='   ',
                   header=None,
                   index_col=0, engine='python' )

n_mus = [1, 2, 4, 12]  # 100]#, 1000]
cost_k = []
k_vals = range(1, 5, 2)
# k_vals = range(1, 30, 6)

for orig_n_mu in n_mus:
    n_mu = orig_n_mu//size
    if rank in range(orig_n_mu%size):
        n_mu += 1
    for k in k_vals:
        cost_n = []
        for n in range(1, n_mu + 1):
            np.random.seed(n * k + k)
            kx = np.random.uniform(df[1].min(), df[1].max(), k)
            np.random.seed(n * k + k + 1)
            ky = np.random.uniform(df[2].min(), df[2].max(), k)
            manh = pd.DataFrame()
            for c in range(k):
                manh[c] = abs(df[1] - kx[c]) + abs(df[2] - ky[c])
            df['center'] = manh.idxmin(axis='columns')
            kx = df.groupby('center').mean()[1]
            ky = df.groupby('center').mean()[2]
            if df.center.unique().shape[0] != k:
                print('not all centers took up clusters at the number', n,
                      'repetition')
                print('the current number of clusters is:',
                      df.center.unique().shape[0], 'instead of', k)
            diff = 10
            while diff > 1e-4:
                cost = manh.min(axis=1).mean()
                for c in df.center.unique():
                    manh[c] = abs(df[1] - kx[c]) + abs(df[2] - ky[c])
                df['center'] = manh.idxmin(axis='columns')
                kx = df.groupby('center').mean()[1]
                ky = df.groupby('center').mean()[2]
                new_cost = manh.min(axis=1).mean()
                diff = cost - new_cost
            cost_n.append(new_cost)
        cost_k.append([k, rank, n_mu, orig_n_mu, cost_n])
print('process #', rank, 'is done here')
all_cost = comm.gather(cost_k, root = 0)
if (rank == 0):
    print('check point #1')
    all_cost = np.reshape(all_cost, newshape=(-1,len(cost_k[0])))
    print('the shape of all cost is', all_cost.shape)
    res = pd.DataFrame(all_cost, columns=['k_val', 'rank', 'n_mu', 'orig_n_mu','cost_res'])
    noruns = (res.n_mu == 0)
    res = res[~noruns].copy()
    res.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    print('check point #2')
    cost_funcs = pd.DataFrame(res.cost_res.to_list())
    print('check point #3')
    km_df = pd.merge(res, cost_funcs, how='outer',left_index=True, right_index=True)
    print('check point #4')
    km_df.drop(columns='cost_res', inplace = True)

    km_df['avg_final_cost'] = cost_funcs.apply(np.nanmean, axis =1)
    km_df['std_final_cost'] = cost_funcs.apply(np.nanstd, axis =1)
    km_df['min_final_cost'] = cost_funcs.apply(min, axis =1)
    km_df['max_final_cost'] = cost_funcs.apply(max, axis =1)

    km_df.to_csv('km_df_test_para.csv')

# km_df
```

The resulting csv looks something like this:
[sample csv screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhQkw.png)

Here n is the number of runs on each core and orig_n is the total number of runs on which I am supposed to do my analysis, record time, check std, mean etc. Columns 0,1,2,... are results from each single run, with column name being the number of run on a single core.

Now I need to have all these runs grouped by n_orig. But have no idea how to tell pandas to put all the values with same n_orig and k in the same row. As you can tell, I'm very new to mpi as well and don't know how else to go about gathering my data. Gather and Gatherv commands keep dropping the error '0'.

I'd appreciate any help you can give :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully what you mean, but maybe sorting the rows by `n_orig` and `k_val` would be enough?

```
km_df.sort_values(by=['n_orig', 'k_val'], inplace=True)
```

Or maybe you can split `km_df` into smaller dataframes of constant `n_orig` and `k_val`:

```
from itertools import product

groups = []
for n_orig, k_val in product(km_df['n_orig'].unique(), km_df['k_val'].unique()):
    sel = (km_df['n_orig'] == n_orig) & (km_df['k_val'] == k_val)
    groups.append(km_df[sel])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I figured it out last night: I simply don't need to save the n_mu, but (as you suggest) only save according to k_val.
It does not matter which repetition/process the result came from, but only which k they belong to.